# iptables NAT for Dockerized VPN Server

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, docker, nat

I want to setup a vpn server on my VPS using Docker.

Many VPN servers like **OpenVPN** need firewall NAT rules and other firewall rules to work.

as [official documents](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern) suggests:

> You may have heard that there should be "one process per container"

But in almost all of VPN images I found, they run both **iptables** and **vpn server** on same container,

some of this images listed here:

- [kylemanna/openvpn](https://hub.docker.com/r/kylemanna/openvpn/)
- [ptlange/openvpn](https://hub.docker.com/r/ptlange/openvpn/)
- [linuxserver/openvpn-as](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openvpn-as/)

So, my question is How to run **vpn server** and **iptables** in spread images for working together?

Is there any **docker networking solution** for this?

Or, Can I use docker host's iptables for NAT and have a container that only vpn server is running on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:
iptables is not a process.  It is a user-interface into a kernel module.

More in-depth information:
  iptables actually configures kernel modules that sit inline with the network stack.  As these kernel modules are configured, network traffic is manipulated.  It is a configuration tool.  iptables itself does not run continuously like a daemon or other process.

Comment: containers and host are shared in kernel, dose changing this configurations in one container affect others?

Comment: By design, No.  Containers are designed to be self-contained.  Docker runs each container within its' own network namespace, meaning that iptables rules, interface names, etc... are only limited to the container itself.  You should not be able to block traffic outside the container.  You can, however, block any traffic generated within the container (or leaving the container), and prevent it from reaching the host, or the other containers or other networks.